# Facebook $facebook->getSignedRequest(); and signed_request error

Tags: facebook

I am using getSignedRequest(); and signed_request to check wether or not a visitor likes the page.

When i go to my Page Tab, that shows an external website in the iframe, getSignedRequest(); and signed_request pulls the information correctly and shows it on my index.php page. But once i like (or dislike the page) and even do a window.location.reload(); - or when i navigate away from the index.php page and back to it again, getSignedRequest(); and signed_request do not fire. When i navigate to my index.php and do a manual refresh of my browser, getSignedRequest(); and signed_request fire and everything is fine.

Does anyone know what i might be doing wrong? Why does getSignedRequest(); and signed_request only fire once?

Here's the Page in question:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/RT/367570243261944?sk=app_327979357253049

I have tried both of these methods:

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
```

and also

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
    $encoded_sig = null;
    $payload = null;
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
    $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
    $signed_request = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true),true);
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: The documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ suggest that signed_request will only be sent on the initial load thus , you may have to save it to retrieve it later